# Calculating a date in access reports?

Tags: ms-access, report

I have a report where the user enters a FROM and TO date. What I'm trying to do is allow the user to view the inventory of the last day of the previous month. So lets take for example: user enters 12/7/2015, I want to be able to show the beginning inventory between 1/1/2000 and the last day of this dates (12/7/2015) which would be 11/30. I'm running this in VB6 just to make sure the number are correct. I've seen other answers on SO but for some reason I'm getting different results.

I try to run this but get a weird date...

```
?DateSerial(Year(12/1/2015),Month(12/1/2015),0)
```

Thsi gives me the following results...

```
11/30/1899
```

So the date seems to be okay, but the year is way off. Why?

Comment: Delimit date values with `#` characters.  Access interprets `12/1/2015` to mean 12 divided by 1 divided by 2015, which is `5.95533498759305E-03`.  And then `Year(12/1/2015)` returns 1899.  Access understands `#12/1/2015#` to be the date Dec 1, 2015.  So `Year(#12/1/2015#)` returns 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Date:

```
DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),0)
```

or, for a specific month:

```
DateSerial(Year(#12/1/2015#),Month(#12/1/2015#),0)
```